# Animal commodification

Tags: kant, justice, deontology, animal-welfare, animals

Is it morally or ethically justified to commodify animals (i.e., such as the tiger temple when it was a thing)? Should humans treat animals' ends (telos) with as much respect as we do ourselves? Finally, is a question such as this dependent on the culture to which one resides (collectivistic vs individualistic)?

Comment: Whether animals are ends in themselves depends on whether they are autonomous rational agents, and for Kant and his contemporaries they were not. See [SEP, The Moral Status of Animals](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-animal/) for modern approaches.